# Loop Function to find a Square root of a number

Tags: python, loops, square-root

The question is 
To find the square root of number ‘N’.using this procedure, we must implement the
following process:

1. Guess a value for the square root of N
2. Divide N by that guess
3. Average the result with your original guess to get your new guess
4. Go to step 2 and repeat

---

I have set the code to return the Guess once it is within 0.5 of the previous Guess, and if its not to repeat the function. I'm not sure how to make it repeat or how to close the loop.

```
def SqrRt(Number,Guess):
while Guess2 == ((Estimate+Guess)/2):
    if (Estimate - Guess2) <= 0.5:
        return Guess2
    elif (Estimate - Guess2) >= -0.5:
        return Guess2
    else:
       Estimate = (Number/Guess)
    Guess2 = Estimate + 1
```

answer = SqrRt(34567823321421,500000)
print(answer)

Comment: `if (Estimate - Guess2) = < 0.5` -- that's a `SyntaxError`. Do you mean `if (Estimate - Guess2) <= 0.5`? Also your while loop is also a `SyntaxErrror`. You need to post actual working code (even if it doesn't give the right answer).

Comment: The while loop is not only a `SyntaxError`, it doesn't really make sense either.

Comment: @FHTMitchell of all the syntax errors in this (while loop coming at the end of code with no conditions, no ':' anywhere besides after `def`, this is the one you choose :P

Comment: You should calculate your next guess before you try to decide if you should stop. If you find out you can stop, you can return right there, which will end that looping immediately.

Also, you can use abs to calculate the absolute value of the difference between your old guess and your new guess, because you're comparing magnitudes of differences.

Comment: So i have fixed the syntax errors but im still not sure how to close off my loop

Comment: On the side, if you will be writing Python for more than the current exercise, please read PEP 8.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Babylonian Method means solving (S^2 - V) = 0. Here, S is the square root of V, which is to be found. Applying Newtons Approximation leads to an iterative method where 'x_new = (x_prev + V / x_prev) / 2'. The first 'x_prev' needs to be estimated.

The iteration converges monotonously. Thus a check against a delta in development is sufficient.

> ```
> x      = V / 2.0       # First estimate
> prev_x = x + 2 * Delta # Some value for that 'while' holds
> while abs(prev_x - x) > Delta:
>     prev_x = x
>     x      = (x + V/x) / 2.0
> square_root = x
> ```

Choose Delta to be arbitrarily small (e.g. 0.0001).

Comment: Beat me to it :p

Comment: I looked at some of this Babylonian methods but they confuse me so i was trying to find an alternative

Comment: Honestly speaking, your method is a little more confusing to me than the Babylonian (smiley).

Comment: Thanks @Frank-ReneSchäfer this is probably the best method and i will use it. I just posted another question about why the code is outputting an incorrect figure.

Answer (score 0):

**First off**

You need code that will actually run at all for a question like this. I suggest that your code should look more like this:

```
def SqrRt(Number,Guess):
    while Guess2 == ((Estimate+Guess)/2):
        if (Estimate - Guess2) <= 0.5:
            return Guess2
        elif (Estimate - Guess2) >= -0.5:
            return Guess2
        else:
           Estimate = (Number/Guess)
        Guess2 = Estimate + 1
answer = SqrRt(34567823321421,500000)
print(answer) 
#Number to Use - 34567823321421
#Answer - 5879440.732
```

Comment: I get an error stating"                                                                                         while Guess2 == ((Estimate+Guess)/2):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Guess2' referenced before assignment"                 Im assuming because i havn't closed my loop it hasnt defined guess2 yet?

Comment: Oops. I'll fix that later as I'm in class